# Is vimscript a reasonable tag?

Tags: discussion, scope

I just opened [a question about vimscript](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/85/what-is-an-effective-way-to-learn-vimscript). Irrespective of the merits of that particular question, does it make sense to use the `vimscript` tag? Arguably many/most questions about vim will end up with a small snippet of vimscript, even if it is only a one-liner to be pasted into a `~/.vimrc`. When should we use this tag?

Comment: `vimscript` is an informal name for `VimL`. I prefer the latter.

Answer (score 5):

My opinion; `vimscript` is a valid tag only when the question is primarily about *programming* in vimscript, typically when the vimscript being discussed is more than a one-liner. The end result in the vim editor is incidental or an aside as far as the question is concerned.